# How can I interrupt a Reader when it "hangs" (need a timeout on Reader.read() )

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, serial-port, webapi

This question is related to a situation that occurred when using Chrome Serial API but probably could be relevant to any ReadableStream. I studied the documentation and probably missed some feature or pattern.

A simple program is running in Chrome browser, accessing CW keyer (based on Arduino, but this is not important).

The application sends a command to the keyer and expects two binary bytes or a string as a response (particular format depends on the command sent and is not important).

In case that the serial device (not the USB/serial adapter, but the Arduino) misses the command for whatever reason, response is never sent and the function `expectResponse()` below will never return any data, nor will it throw any exception. As a result, the Reader remains locked, the ReadableStream therefore cannot be closed and as a consequence, the serial port cannot be closed either.

Also, depending on the application structure, in case of other command sent successfully to the keyer, it may be not possible to read the second response because the first reader blocks the stream and until it is released, new Reader cannot be created.

```js
async function expectResponse( serialPort ) {
   const reader = serialPort.readable.getReader() ;
   let { value, done } = await reader.read() ; // this never returns because no data arrive, not possible to "break"
}

async function disconnect( serialPort ) {
   // ... some cleanup ...
   // naive attempt to unlock ReadableStream before closing 
   await serialPort.readable.getReader().releaseLock() // this will throw exception - cannot create  new reader while another one is still active and locks the stream
   // ...
   await serialPort.close(); // this will throw exception - cannot close port because readable stream is locked
}
```

`serialPort` is the object returned by `navigator.serial.requestPort()`

I am convinced I must have missed something important in API docs (`ReadableStream` or `Reader` API, not `Serial` API), but I did not find solution.

P.S. in the real app `serialPort` is a global variable, but it does not matter, does it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think `ReadableStream` has timeouts built in.

I'd use [`Promise.race`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) with the other promise being your timeout:

```
let { value, done } = await Promise.race([
    reader.read(),
    new Promise((_, reject) => setTimeout(reject, TIMEOUT, new Error("timeout")))
]);
```

*(You'd probably put that `new Promise` code in a utility function.)*

`Promise.race` watches the promises race, settling its promise based on the first settlement it sees of the promises in the array you give it. So if `read`'s promise is fulfilled (or rejected) before the timeout promise rejects, `read`'s settlement dictates the settlement of the `race` promise. Otherwise, the `race` promise settles based on the settlement (in this case, rejection) of the timeout promise.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to "break" the await operation:

According to the documentation the `await reader.read()` will throw `TypeError` if you call `reader.releaseLock()`. (for example with a `setTimeout`)

Doc:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStreamDefaultReader/read

```
try {
    await reader.read();
} catch(e) {
    console.log("you got out from await");
}

setTimeout(function() {
    reader.releaseLock();
}, TIMEOUT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on TJ's answer, I came up with this:

```
function promiseTimeout<T>(promise: Promise<T>, ms = 500): Promise<T> {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/65748368/65387
    let timer: any
    const timeoutPromise = new Promise<T>((_, reject) => {
        timer = setTimeout(() => reject(new Error(`Promise timed out after ${ms}ms`)), ms)
    })
    promise.finally(() => {
        clearTimeout(timer)
    })
    return Promise.race([promise, timeoutPromise])
}
```

Which you can use like this:

```
let {value: chunk, done: readerDone} = await promiseTimeout(reader.read())
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on guttmann's answer, I came up with:

```
async function readOrTimeout(reader: ReadableStreamDefaultReader<Uint8Array>, ms = 500) {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/73436229/65387
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
        reader.releaseLock()
    }, ms)
    try {
        return await reader.read()
    } finally {
        clearTimeout(timer)
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
let {value: chunk, done: readerDone} = await readOrTimeout(reader)
```